# Disable WP search but not for products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to disable the default Wordpress search and set it to 404, this  can be done with

```
function fb_filter_query( $query, $error = true ) {

if ( is_search() ) {
    $query->is_search = false;
    $query->query_vars[s] = false;
    $query->query[s] = false;

    // to error
    if ( $error == true )
        $query->is_404 = true;
}
}

add_action( 'parse_query', 'fb_filter_query' );
add_filter( 'get_search_form', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
```

But I still need to be able to do a product search (the default Woocommerce product search). But any url with /?s= and without &post_type=product should be 404. How can I modify the code above?

I tried the code mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
if ( is_search() ) {
   if ( ! empty( $_GET['post_type'] ) && 'product' === $_GET['post_type'] ) {
       return;
   }
   ...
}
```

Or maybe

```
if ( is_search() ) {
    if ( 'product' === $query->post_type ) {
      return;
    }
    ...
}
```

I haven't tested it, but the first approach should work if the post_type is in the url.

Comment: could you please write the full code? When I add your snippet I am getting a blank page with error.